# Determine if a vector is ordered

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to determine if a vector is either always increasing or always decreasing in R.

Ideally, if I had these three vectors:

```
asc=c(1,2,3,4,5)
des=c(5,4,3,2,1)
non=c(1,3,5,4,2)
```

I would hope that the first two would return TRUE, and the last would return FALSE.

I tried a few approaches. First, I tried:

```
> is.ordered(asc)
[1] FALSE
> is.ordered(des)
[1] FALSE
> is.ordered(non)
[1] FALSE
```

And I also tried:

```
> order(non)
[1] 1 5 2 4 3
```

And hoped that I could simply compare this vector with `1,2,3,4,5` and `5,4,3,2,1`, but even that returns a string of logicals, rather than a single true or false:

```
> order(non)==c(1,2,3,4,5)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: In Matlab I would check that the `diff` of the vector is either always greater than zero, or always less than zero: `all(diff(myVec)>=0) || all(diff(myVec)<=0);` . I am sure something similar exists in `r`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe [`is.unsorted`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.unsorted.html) is the function your looking for

```
> is.unsorted(asc)
[1] FALSE
> is.unsorted(rev(des)) # here you need 'rev'
[1] FALSE
> is.unsorted(non)
[1] TRUE
```

From the Description of `is.unsorted` you can find:

> Test if an object is not sorted (in increasing order), without the cost of sorting it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way using `?is.unsorted`:

```
is.sorted <- function(x, ...) {
    !is.unsorted(x, ...) | !is.unsorted(rev(x), ...)
}
```

Have a look at the additional arguments to `is.unsorted`, which can be passed here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without is.unsorted() to check if to vectors are sorted. This function will return true, if all elements in the vector given are sorted in an ascending manner or false if not:

```
is.sorted <- function(x) {
  if(all(sort(x, decreasing = FALSE) == x)) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna pedantic here.  You don't de `if else` condition.  When you write `all(sort(x, decreasing = FALSE) == x)` this is already a logical value.  So returning TRUE when that's TRUE, and FALSE when it isn't is like a tautology.  Thought you should know.